# Any HTML tag or attribute to avoid Apple text recognition?

Tags: html, macos, safari

On some text logo Safari does enable text recognition and hovering it select the text.
This can cause an issue with navigation.

Any HTML tag to avoid this new feature?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it works for SVGs - I also think that if your image is a link then it prioritises the link

Comment: logo is already a SVG but latest Mac automatically activate an OCR future